# Local transportation from/to ORD Chicago Airport?

Tags: usa, public-transport, chicago, ord

**Some background:**

There are five of us and each is carrying 3 huge check in bags.
We are arriving at ORD on Monday 27th August by 8:00AM and expect to clear customs in 2 hours. We would need transportation to reach our place of stay around 10AM and a return trip back to ORD airport by 7:00PM.

**Problem:**

We want to decide the place to stay but unable to understand how costly it would be for transportation and how much time would be required.
There are 2 good places I found on Airbnb:

- S Addison St,Bensenville ($109)
- Irving Park, North Elston Avenue ($84)

I am not aware of how taxi/van charges would be applicable as this is my first time in the US.
Also, I am not aware of how feasible it would be to use the train services.

Please recommend your suggestions based on feasibility and cost effectiveness.

Comment: Have you tried Uber, Lyft, Google Maps, or Taxi Finder?

Comment: On top of this from what I am reading you are a group of 5 with 15 checked in bags.  You will need a big SUV because I don't think that even a minivan will be able to handle this much luggage.

Comment: That's a lot of baggage for a one-day trip?

Comment: @MichaelHampton I think it's a not a one day trip but a move.  See other questions.

Comment: @Karlson You're right...and I actually tried to look up flights to his actual destination, and it appears impossible to book a single ticket for PNQ-CMX (or even BOM-CMX) at all! Something strange about that airport...

Comment: @MichaelHampton There are only 2 scheduled flights to that airport: http://www.houghtoncounty.org/flights-arrivals.php

Comment: @Karlson Right, but United codeshares them so it ought to be possible to book tickets there from virtually anywhere. Give it a try yourself and see if you can actually get a price quote for any day in August.

Comment: @MichaelHampton http://www.kayak.com/flights/bom-CMX/2015-08-13/2015-09-22

Comment: That works. It's absurd that it costs $700 more for a flight there, when I can do ORD-CMX separately for ~ $250. The free bus is even better, though...

Comment: @MichaelHampton Exactly.

Comment: @Karlson I found various websites from Google search. But I am not sure which type of vehicle would be able to take that much baggage?

Comment: @MichaelHampton we are shifting for 2 years to Houghton. The Hancock (CMX) airport has only 2 daily flights and most of the times they are delayed. Our university has been kind enough to organise a bus service from ORD to University for only $75 per person.

Comment: And we would not be needing the cab ride for the other option of Irving Park, right? I tried to understand from the railway website but the terms are new to me. Can you please tell me would the train be a better option as we would be needing to/fro airport transportation and looking to avoid huge expenditure?

Comment: @cool_coder Uber XL should be able to in a Chevy Suburban but if you're taking this much luggage with you public transport isn't really an option. since I can't see how you would bring luggage carts onto the trains or buses.   I'd look to store tge luggage for a day if that's how long you are in Chicago.

Answer (score 2):

First, a quick primer on the train options in Chicago.  There are two train systems, the Chicago Transit Authority (CTA) and Metra.  The CTA is mainly designed to shuttle people around within the city of Chicago;  Metra is mainly designed to shuttle people from the surrounding towns into the downtown core and back out again (i.e., "commuter rail".)  The CTA has a terminal right inside O'Hare airport;  Metra has a [station somewhat outside of the airport](http://www.flychicago.com/OHare/EN/GettingToFrom/PublicTransportation/Metra-Information.aspx), with a shuttle bus that runs to & from the station.

With that in mind, here's my take on the two AirBnB locations you mentioned:

- Bensenville is a suburb of Chicago, just south of the airport.  Public transit there would be a real hassle.  You'd have to take the shuttle bus to the Metra "O'Hare Transfer" station, take the train towards the city a few stops, get off, transfer to a different line going back out towards a different suburb, and then get off at the Bensenville stop.  From there, you'd have to walk to wherever the AirBnB location is;  on the map, it looks like it probably wouldn't be more than a kilometer, but that's a long distance when you're toting bags.  However, getting from O'Hare to Bensenville with a cab from the airport would be relatively easy;  it wouldn't even require getting on the freeways, which would be a real plus if you're arriving around rush hour.  [Cab fares are available here;](http://www.cityofchicago.org/city/en/depts/bacp/supp_info/2012_passenger_information.html)  the distance from O'Hare to Bensenville is about 8–10 miles, so the total fare would work out to be in the $25–30 range (before tip, which would be expected;  this also assumes no time stuck in traffic, for which you'll also be charged.)  Note that since Bensenville is outside the Chicago city limits, there's a 50% surcharge tacked onto the fare.
- Irving Park is a neighborhood of Chicago on the north side.  The CTA Blue Line has one terminal in the O'Hare Airport, and would take you directly from there to the Irving Park neighborhood.  However, from there you would still need to walk a substantial distance to get to Elston Avenue.  For a cab ride, the distance appears to be about 12 miles, which would yield a fare of about $25 (again, before tip.)

Given that your ride from the airport will be at 10 AM (at the end of the morning rush hour, but still with substantial traffic) and that your ride back to the airport will need to be at around 6 PM (definitely during the evening rush hour), I would go with the Bensenville location.  Chicago traffic can get pretty bad, and I would place a premium on being able to get to and from the airport quickly.

Also:  hailing a cab at the curb may not be your best option in this case;  you might want to look into a car service (aka "limousine service") and pre-arranging a ride to & from the airport.  For the amount of people and luggage that you have, it would definitely save you hassle and might even save you money.  However, I have zero personal experience with doing this, so I'll let someone else speak to the feasibility of this option.

Comment: All of this with 15 bags.

Comment: Doesn't ORD have a luggage storage service? You could reduce your essential luggage to carry to the hotel significantly.

Comment: @Kent:  [Currently there are no facilities or provision for the storage of luggage at O'Hare International Airport.](http://www.flychicago.com/OHare/EN/Connect/FAQs/Frequently-Asked-Questions.aspx#topic3)